# Android creating dynamically relative layout gives nullpointer

Tags: android

Before oncreate:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout;
```

oncreate:

```
    rLayout = new RelativeLayout();
    rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    setContentView(rLayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);

    rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    imgBytes = object.getObjectImageBlob();
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

    imageAnswer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    imageAnswer.setTag(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectAnswer());
    imageAnswer.setId(R.id.imgAnswer);

    rLayout.removeAllViews();
    rLayout.addView(imageAnswer,rLayParams);
```

This works. But i create first instance then findview. Normally this is not way.

So, when i change to this:

oncreate:

```
    RelativeLayout rLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);

    rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    imgBytes = object.getObjectImageBlob();
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

    imageAnswer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    imageAnswer.setTag(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectAnswer());
    imageAnswer.setId(R.id.imgAnswer);

    rLayout.addView(imageAnswer,rLayParams);
```

It gives nullpointer for addview line:

```
rLayout.addView(imageAnswer,rLayParams);
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    tools:context=".games.MatchingGame">  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which is true way, creating with new RelativeLayout() or second one, but wht nullpointer?

When i put setcontentview nothing changes also. Or enabling disabling removeall views. A lot of changes i tried but did not work.

Full activity full without deleting anything:

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.caneraydin.androidwithlogin.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.caneraydin.androidwithlogin.R;
import com.example.caneraydin.androidwithlogin.domains.ObjectObject;
import com.example.caneraydin.androidwithlogin.domains.TrainingObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;    

public class MatchingGame extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnDragListener {
    String TAG = "tag";
    RelativeLayout rLayout;
    int trainingID,objectCount;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    List<TrainingObject> trainingObjectList;
    ObjectObject object;
    byte[] imgBytes;
    int isAnswered = 0;
    Handler handler;
    int isDragged=0;

    //   Bitmap bmpAnswer,bmpOne, bmpTwo, bmpThree, bmpFour, bmpFive;

    ImageView imageAnswer, imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour, imageFive;

    //  ImageView image;

    Bitmap bmp;
    CountDownTimer cTimer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"1isanswered : "+isAnswered);
        Log.d(TAG, "matchinggame OnCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        rLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        object = new ObjectObject();
        imageAnswer=new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(rLayout);
        // Log.d(TAG, "mx");
        // rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

        trainingID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("trainingid");
        trainingObjectList = new ArrayList<TrainingObject>();

        trainingObjectList = dbHandler.getAllTrainingObject(trainingID);
        //// TODO: 02.05.2016 egitim kismi oalcak burda tek tek gosterilecek

        rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        // Handler handler = new Handler(); Log.d(TAG,"2isanswered : "+isAnswered);
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            Log.d(TAG,"i:"+i); 
            Log.d(TAG,"3tisanswered : "+isAnswered);
            final int finalI = i;

            //  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            //  @Override
            //     public void run() {Log.d(TAG,"thread i: "+finalI);
            Log.d(TAG,"4isanswered : "+isAnswered);
            isAnswered = 0;
            TrainingObject trainingObject = new TrainingObject();
            trainingObject = trainingObjectList.get(finalI);
            objectCount = 2;
            //test icin
            Log.d(TAG,"testicin trainingobjectid: "+trainingObject.getTrainingobjectID());
            object = dbHandler.getObjectObject(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectAnswer());

            if(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectThree()!=0) objectCount++;
            if(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectFour()!=0) objectCount++;
            if(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectFive()!=0) objectCount++;
            Log.d(TAG,"matchinggame objcount: "+objectCount);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);

            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

            imgBytes = object.getObjectImageBlob();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

            imageAnswer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            imageAnswer.setTag(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectAnswer());
            imageAnswer.setId(R.id.imgAnswer);
            rLayout.removeAllViews();
            rLayout.addView(imageAnswer,rLayParams);

            rLayParams = null;
            object = null;
            bmp = null;
            imgBytes = null;

            rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);
            imageOne = new ImageView(MatchingGame.this);
            object = dbHandler.getObjectObject(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectOne());
            imgBytes = object.getObjectImageBlob();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);
            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,R.id.imgAnswer);
            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

            imageOne.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            imageOne.setTag(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectOne());
            imageOne.setId(R.id.imgOne);
            rLayout.addView(imageOne,rLayParams);

            rLayParams = null;;
            object = null;
            bmp = null;
            imgBytes = null;

            rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);
            imageTwo = new ImageView(MatchingGame.this);
            object = dbHandler.getObjectObject(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectTwo());
            imgBytes = object.getObjectImageBlob();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.imgAnswer);

            imageTwo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            imageTwo.setTag(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectTwo());
            imageTwo.setId(R.id.imgTwo);
            rLayout.addView(imageTwo,rLayParams);

            imageOne.setOnDragListener(MatchingGame.this);
            imageTwo.setOnDragListener(MatchingGame.this);

            imageAnswer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { Log.d(TAG,"6isanswered : "+isAnswered);
                    Log.d(TAG,"matchinggame setontouch");
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"matchinggame setontouch if yes");
                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); Log.d(TAG,"7isanswered : "+isAnswered);
                        return true;
                    } else { Log.d(TAG,"8isanswered : "+isAnswered);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            imageAnswer.setOnDragListener(MatchingGame.this);
            Log.d(TAG,"*");
            while(isAnswered==0){
                //Log.d(TAG,"*");
            }

            //  }
          //  }, 30000*finalI );Log.d(TAG,"thread sonrasi: "+finalI); Log.d(TAG,"5isanswered : "+isAnswered);
        }Log.d(TAG,"ff");
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"matchinggame ontouch");
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View receivingLayoutView, DragEvent dragEvent) { Log.d(TAG,"9isanswered : "+isAnswered);
        //  Log.d(TAG, "match game ondrag start");
        //  View draggedImageView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
        //  ImageView draggedImg = (ImageView) draggedImageView;

        // Log.d(TAG, "ondrag start receiving visibility: "+receivingLayoutView.getVisibility()+" draggged visib "+draggedImageView.getVisibility());
        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                //  Log.d(TAG, "drag action started");

                // Determines if this View can accept the dragged data
                if (dragEvent.getClipDescription()
                        .hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    //     Log.d(TAG, "Can accept this data");

                    // returns true to indicate that the View can accept the dragged data.
                    return true;

                } else {
                    //     Log.d(TAG, "Can not accept this data");

                }

                // Returns false. During the current drag and drop operation, this View will
                // not receive events again until ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is sent.
                return false;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //  Log.d(TAG, "drag action entered");
                //                the drag point has entered the bounding box
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                //   Log.d(TAG, "drag action location");
            /*triggered after ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED
                stops after ACTION_DRAG_EXITED*/
                receivingLayoutView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                // Log.d(TAG, "drag action exited");
                //                the drag shadow has left the bounding box
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:  Log.d(TAG, "drag action droop");
                ImageView dropOntoImg = (ImageView) receivingLayoutView;
                View draggedImageView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
                // ImageView draggedImg = (ImageView) draggedImageView;

                Log.d(TAG,"droponto: "+receivingLayoutView.getTag()+" dropped: "+draggedImageView.getTag());

                //  Log.d(TAG,  "swtich önesi "+ dropOntoImg.getId());

                Log.d(TAG,  "swtich önesii "+dropOntoImg.getTag()+" vs "+draggedImageView.getTag());

                        // ImgTags imgtag =  ImgTags.valueOf(dropOntoImg.getTag().toString()
                        //.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH))
                //) ;
                //    Log.d(TAG,  "swtich ön esi "+imgtag.toString());
//// TODO: 5/15/2016 baska yere bırakinca da false veriyor 
                if(dropOntoImg.getTag().equals(draggedImageView.getTag())){
                //    Log.d(TAG,"true "+dropOntoImg.getTag()+" droppeged true with dragged"+ draggedImageView.getTag() + "");
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                 //   Log.d(TAG,"false "+dropOntoImg.getTag()+" droppeged true with dragged"+ draggedImageView.getTag() + "");
                    return false;
                }

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                isAnswered = 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "isAnswered "+isAnswered);
                draggedImageView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
                Log.d(TAG, "drag action ended");
                Log.d(TAG, "getResult: " + dragEvent.getResult());
                // receivingLayoutView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // draggedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //                if the drop was not successful, set the ball to visible
                if (!dragEvent.getResult()) { Log.d(TAG,"10isanswered : "+isAnswered);isAnswered =2;
                    Log.d(TAG, "false, setting visible");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"False",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    final View droppedView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
                    droppedView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            droppedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }); Log.d(TAG,"11isanswered : "+isAnswered);
                }
                else{ Log.d(TAG,"12isanswered : "+isAnswered);isAnswered=1;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"True",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Log.d(TAG,"13isanswered : "+isAnswered);
                }

                //// TODO: 5/15/2016 burda response kaydedilecek

                return true;
            // An unknown action type was received.
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your full activity class

Comment: And your `rLayParams` is not null??

Comment: you have still not added full activity file

Comment: yes not null. i test with different things, always showing rLayout null.even before layoutparams. i added full activity and put snippets to oncreate snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

this tries to find the relative layout from currentView.

to have the currentView be from xml, you need to call setContentView with that layout id like

```
setContentView(R.layout.myactivity.xml)
```

this line seems to be missing from your code. until you have this line ,

> rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout); will
>   return null

Comment: I did

 rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matchgame);//the parent of relative_layout


still  null. but when i did
setContentView(R.layout.activity_matchgame);//the parent of relative_layout
 rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
it worked. it waits until oncreate finishes to set up layout, why?

I am inside for loop, every iteration i need to change layout in moment

Comment: can you come to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

The first approach of creating objects and using find view by id is fine. because first of all, the object should be created and then you can access inside properties, but the opposite is not true. SetcontentView will inform which layout to be rendered for corresponding activity .